# Good way to integrate query-layout with reactive templates + async data sources?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, meteor, handlebars.js, jquery-layout

I'm working on a Meteor app that gets data from Facebook & I would like to use jquery-layout for presentation. I suspected that there might be some "subtleties" when trying to use jquery to modify HTML in reactive templates, so I set up a relatively simple test case that goes something like this (paraphrased for brevity)...

```
<body>
{{> mainTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="mainTemplate">
  {{#with userInfo}}  
  {{> partialNorth}}  
  {{> partialWest}}  
  {{> partialCenter}}  
  {{> partialEast}}  
  {{/with}}  
  {{layItOut}}  
</template>
```

Template.mainTemplate.userInfo returns contents of a Session variable that starts with a default value and asynchronously get updated with info from Facebook.

Template.mainTemplate.layItOut sets up a call to Meteor.defer with a callback fcn that actually executes the 5 lines of jquery-layout code.

And that seems to work pretty well...

- the initial display is as expected/intended (although there's a brief period where the page is not laid out)
- any updates to the reactive context cause re-execution of the layout (again, w/brief-but-visible re-layout)

So, why am I whining? Mostly I would like to find a cleaner approach that does away with the noticeable re-layout activity.

I *could* make the reactive contexts more granular, but I'm not sure that this would really help.

Alternatively, I suppose I could experiment with directly controlling rendering (e.g., via Meteor.ui.render() , but that sounds like a lot of work ;-)

I think what I'd really like is either

a) a way to hook into Meteor render events

or better still

b) a cleaner way to connect query-layout to templates

Thoughts?

Comment: This is a tricky one.  I'm not sure what jQuery Layout does under the hood.  My personal impression is that it's bound to cause extra flicker, because it does things in code that you can do in pure CSS with absolute positioning (as of IE7).

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to educate myself enough to answer my own question in case anyone else finds it useful.  Bottom line is that I was wrong on several levels; making the reactive contexts more granular *is* the answer (or at least *an* answer).

In the example I gave, I made the whole page reactive by placing all of the rendering within the #each construct.  What I now do is try to make the reactive contexts as small as possible so that only a (relatively) small part of the page is re-rendered on any reactive change and *all* of the reactive elements are contained below (or *way* below) the level of the jquery ui elements.

I.e., something like this:

```
<body>
{{> mainTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="mainTemplate">
```

<s>{{#with userInfo}}</s>

```
{{> partialNorth}} 
{{> partialWest}}  
  ...
```

<s>{{/with}}</s>

```
  {{layItOut}}  
</template>  

<template name="partialNorth">
  <div class="ui-layout-north">  <-- definition for jquery-layout north panel
    <h1>This is the north pane</h1>
    <p>The user data go next:</p><br />
    {{> templateUserData}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="templateUserData">
  <div>
    {{#with theUserData}}  <-- Assumes a helper function 'theUserData' for this template
      <p>First name: {{first_name}}</p>
      <p>Last name: {{last_name}}</p>
      ...
    {{/with}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Once you have the reactive elements below the jquery ui elements (I have tried it with panels, tabs, accordions, buttons and pop-ups so far) the whole thing works just like it said it would in the shiny brochure! ;-)